# header() method doesn't work

Tags: php, database, methods, header

I want to make it redirect but it doesn't come back. I know before header() method shouldn't call any output result but I don't know where I have written methods which returns a output.
its my source:

```
<?php include 'database.php';

$message =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']);

date_default_timezone_set('Iran');
$time = date('h:i:s a',time());

if(!isset($message) || $message == ''){
    $error = "Fill the textbox";
```

> ```
>   header("Location: harf.php?error=".urlencode($error));//changed
> ```

```
    exit();
} else {

    $query = "INSERT INTO main (user,message,time) VALUES('ROBOT','$message','$time')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query)) {
```

> ```
>       die('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));//changed
> ```

```
    } else {
        header("Location: harf.php");
        exit();
    }
}?>
```

thanks

Comment: do you get any error/warning or exception ?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the start of the script, see if you get any errors. Also check if there's no white space in between the `<?php` starting that and the actual file, something like `&nbsp<?php`

Comment: Is the path to harf.php correct?

Comment: You have to user absolute path instead of harf.php

Comment: i don't get any error or everything like that and the project work well.the. Im working in host server.

Comment: DV for the *Stealth* edit without marking your edit as an edit or showing it in your question that `Locaton` was a typo.

Comment: and this `mysql_error` that's incorrect. you're missing the `i` for it. we also don't know for sure if your DB connection is correct and not using another kind of MySQL API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spelling mistake here

```
header("Locaton: harf.php?error=".urlencode($error));
```

change with this

```
header("Location: harf.php?error=".urlencode($error));
```

Comment: The OP made a *Stealth* edit without marking it as an edit or telling everyone that they made a typo.

Comment: yeah, that gets people's answers downvoted for mistakes like that @IRDN